# Incrementing key value when save data to local storage

Tags: javascript

I want to save different objects with different key to local storage every time my button clicked. But always key == 0 and records doesn't create, one record in local storage only update,I think this is because key is always same. How I can change this,to put different objects to local storage?

```
(function() {

    window.onload = function() {
        var key = 0;
         var storage = new Storage();
        document.getElementById('buttonCreate').onclick = function() {
            var topicValue = document.getElementById("create-topic").value;
            var statusValue = document.getElementById("create-status").value;
            var descriptionValue = document.getElementById("create-description").value;
            var ticket = {
                topic: topicValue,
                status: statusValue,
                description: descriptionValue
            };
            storage.set(key, ticket);
            key++;
        }
    }
})();
function Storage() {
  this._ITEMS_DESCRIPTOR = 'items';
}
Storage.prototype.get = function() {
  var fromStorage = localStorage.getItem(this._ITEMS_DESCRIPTOR);
  return fromStorage ? JSON.parse(fromStorage) : [];
};
Storage.prototype.set = function(key, items) {
  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(items));
};
```

Comment: Your code does create different entries in localstorage, press F12 and check it. How are you saying that records are not created?

Comment: my code create record with key 0 only

Comment: Try posting a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

#### As localstorage API is implemented

**You set an item for a keyName (1st argument):**

```
localStorage.setItem(keyName, keyValue);
```

**You get an item for a keyName:**

```
var aValue = localStorage.getItem(keyName);
```

*So in your case your Storage Object should be adapted since it seems like you need multiples keys but your get storage will only retrieve a fixed key='items'.*

**So, modify your Storage.get and pass a key when you call it:**

```
function Storage() {
  this._ITEMS_DESCRIPTOR = 'items'; // I guess a default key?
}
// let key be specified when method is called, or by default set it to the private property _ITEMS_DESCRIPTOR
Storage.prototype.get = function(key) {
  var fromStorage = localStorage.getItem(key  ? key : this._ITEMS_DESCRIPTOR);
  return fromStorage ? JSON.parse(fromStorage) : [];
};
Storage.prototype.set = function(key, items) {
  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(items));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

your key should be incrementing, but your storage.get is hard coded to a specific key so you'll never be able to retrieve them through its get method.

You should also verify that the method is being invoked

You could try a string vs a number as a key

```
storage.set("topic_" + key, ticket);
// alert("topic set for topic_" + key);
// retrieve and test data storage
// var data = localStorage.getItem("topic_" + key);
// alert("from storage:\n\n" + JSON.stringify(data));
key++;
```

Use F12 to review localStorage or simply test the data that is stored

```
function test(){
   if (localStorage.length == 0)
      alert("no items in localStorage");

   for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
      var key = localStorage.key(i);
      var value = localStorage.getItem(key);
      alert("storage [" + key + "] = " + value);        
   }
}
```